# Can't include PDF file due to "Bad 'Length' attribute in stream"

Tags: includegraphics

I am trying to include some vector graphics saved as pdf, in my tech file. I'm using `\includegraphics`, so my code line is `\includegraphics[width=20mm]{pics/KnickExpohne.pdf}`
It works perfectly fine for other images just not for these two, it seems to have a problem with these particular files. They are very similar, so it might be due to some elements they contain.

Either way, how do I fix this? This is the error code (for the other file it's `Error (3700)`)

```
[1 <./pics/KnickStossohne.pdfSyntax Error (3709): Bad 'Length' attribute in stream

!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./pics/KnickStossohne.pdf): P
DF inclusion: type <error> cannot be copied
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

And here I uploaded the files: [1](http://www.filedropper.com/knickexpohne) [2](http://www.filedropper.com/knickstossohne)

I am on Mac, using TeXShop if that makes a difference.

Happy for any help I can get :)

Answer (score 2):

I have analyzed the first file `KnickStossohne.pdf`. Indeed, the PDF file is invalid. It contains stream objects without length specifications, for example:

```pdf
5 0 obj
<</Type /Pattern/PatternType 1/PaintType 1/TilingType 1/BBox [0 0 28 28]/XStep 28/YStep 28/Resources <</ProcSet [/PDF /ImageC]>>
>>

stream
...
endstream
endobj
```

The dictionary `<<...>>` before the keyword `stream` does not contain `/Length` with the number of bytes in the stream.

Workaround:

Run the file through [PDFtk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFtk) to get the `/Length` inserted:

```
pdftk KnickStossohne.pdf cat output KnickStossohne-fixed.pdf compress
```

and use `KnickStossohne-fixed.pdf` as image. Option `compress` can be omitted, but it decreases the file size, since the original file is not compressed.

**Remark:**

- The length of the stream is required. The reader then knows, where the end of the stream is. Looking for the keyword `endstream` is not reliable, because the stream data can contain the byte sequence `endstream`.

Comment: Related: In other forums, pertaining to print-on-demand books, I often see issues regarding vector artwork. The issues are not by TeX users, but they would also apply to TeX. The problem is that a lot of vector artwork (including some converted to PDF) contains incorrect instructions. The programs creating the artwork, and some viewers, simply work-around the problem, instead of flagging it as error. But then when the final file gets to the printer, it is flagged as error. Thus, many P.O.D. services recommend using only raster artwork, since scalability is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I "run it through pdftk"? Or rather where do I enter the line you wrote? And don't I need to specify where the file is located?

Comment: @RobtAll So if I manage to get this to work in Tex even and send the finished PDF to my printer it will have a problem?

Comment: @LondonLiliput I have added a link to [PDFtk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFtk).

Comment: @LondonLiliput Not necessarily. If you manage to get it fixed, and the complete PDF can be opened in Adobe Reader (free version OK) without complaint, then your file is probably OK. The issues primarily concern print-on-demand services, books with bleed, and PDF/X. If that is not what you are doing, then don't worry about it.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I finally got to my PC and everything works perfectly now. Thank you so much for help! :)